# How to display 0s for time using jquery mask plug in

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using Jquery mask plugin to display time.This mask does not allow to enter more than 2 as 1st number. But my requirement is if I enter '5', it should display as '05:00'.Could anyone please help me, how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this block of code.

```
 $(function() {
            $('input).bind('keydown', function(e) 
             {
              var keyCode = e.keyCode;
                if (keyCode == ? )  //? check its more than 2 
                 {
                  //read the value 5 and update the input with 05:00                    
                  }
              });
        });
```

I am not sure this is what exactly you want. But it will work